# ACL for openldap a group to move one specific DN b/w different organizational units (OU)

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

I can't seem to get this right. I have a bunch of users in a group, `cn=noc,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com`, who should be able to move a list between `ou=internalLists,ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com` to `ou=externalLists,ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com`.

The DN for that list is:

```
cn=mylist,ou=internalLists,ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com
```

This is the ACLs i have for `ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com` subtree:

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=externalLists,ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com"
       by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=noc,ou=Groups,dc=company,dc=com" write
       by * break


access to dn.subtree="ou=internalLists,ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com"
        by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=noc,ou=Groups,dc=company,dc=com" write
        by * break


access to dn.subtree="ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com"
        by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=ops,ou=Groups,dc=company,dc=com" write
        by * read
```

The above ACLs work but they also give the group 'noc' access to move other lists as well. I just want it to restrict to that just one list (cn=mylist). So, I tried the following:

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=externalLists,ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com"
       filter="(cn=mylist)"
           by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=noc,ou=Groups,dc=company,dc=com" write
           by * break


access to dn.subtree="ou=internalLists,ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com"
        filter="(cn=mylist)"
            by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=noc,ou=Groups,dc=company,dc=com" write
            by * break


access to dn.subtree="ou=mail,ou=service,dc=company,dc=com"
        by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=ops,ou=Groups,dc=company,dc=com" write
        by * read
```

This gives me 'Insufficient access' error. What am I doing wrong?